# How can my content script also work in iframes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My content script will insert some buttons into the page.When I click on the button,it will do something,for example console.log("..."),maybe it will use mouse selection.

Is it possible to work when the page has iframes?

Comment: Depends on if the iframe content is in the same domain or not.

Comment: just like http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It is in the same domain.So what can I do?

Comment: @Daedalus That comment makes no sense in the context of a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `all_frames: true` to your [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) declaration in `manifest.json`.

```js
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": [
            "content_script.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I just try it here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html
it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tom `It doesn't work` isn't a problem description; please post the error you are getting in your console.

Comment: @Tom Also make sure you are doing something more prominent than a `console.log` -- it's likely that calls to `console.log` within iframes do not register on the parent page's console. (I haven't tested it, though.)